# Showing different maps in different pages of a website

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

So, i'm new on leaflet.js and i'm trying to present two different leaflet maps on two different pages of my website, i.e, map 1 on page A and map2 on page B.

If i present both map1 and map2 in the same page works well, but when i try to present each one on one page, the second doesn't appear.

Some one can help me with this?
Thank you

Code for my second page of the website

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/scss/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
   crossorigin=""/>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
  
  <title>Circuit A - Predefined Circuits</title>

  <style>
    .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
    .attribution a { color: #ffffff; }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
   

  <header class="header">
    <div class="overlay has-fade"></div>
    
    <nav class="container flex flex-jc-sb flex-ai-c">
      <a href="index.html" class="header__logo hide-for-mobile">
        <img src="images/logo_desktop.png" alt="POCITYF"/> 
      </a>

      <a href="index.html" class="header__logo hide-for-desktop">
        <img src="images/logo_mobile.png" alt="POCITYF"/> 
      </a>

      <a id="btnHamburger" href="#" class="header__toggle hide-for-desktop">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </a>

      <div class="header__links hide-for-mobile">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a><a href="network.html">Network</a><a href="predefined_circuit.html"><b>Predefined Circuit</b></a><a href="create_circuit.html">Create Circuit</a><a target="blank" href="https://www.evoraticket.pt/OBilhete.aspx">Tickets</a><a target="blank" href="https://pocityf.eu/">About</a>
      </div>

      <!-- <a href="#" class="button header__cta hide-for-mobile">Request Invite</a> -->
    </nav>

    <div class="header__menu has-fade">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="network.html">Network</a>
      <a href="predefined_circuit.html"><b>Predefined Circuit</b></a>
      <a href="create_circuit.html">Create Circuit</a>
      <a target="blank" href="https://www.evoraticket.pt/OBilhete.aspx">Tickets</a>
      <a target="blank" href="https://pocityf.eu/">About</a>
    </div>

  </header>
<!-- Editar para baixo -->

<section class="bar container--images"></section>
<section class="info_circuits">

    
...

      <section class="info_circuits__map">
            <section class="maps">
 
            <div id="mapcircuit"></div>
           </section>
          </section>
      
</section>  
 ...

<!--<div class="attribution">
    Coded by <a href="#">UNINOVA</a>
  </div> -->
  
  <script src="app/js/script.js"></script>
  
  <script src="app/js/map_circuita.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Code of maps.js

```
// create a map in the "map" div, set the view to a given place and zoom
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([38.57156160678178, -7.908692129122894], 16);

// add an OpenStreetMap tile layer
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

// add a marker in the given location, attach some popup content to it and open the popup
var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/position.png',

    iconSize:[60, 40], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor:   [30, 40], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
});
L.marker([38.57266152778955, -7.907425130974091],{icon:greenIcon}).addTo(map)

    .bindPopup('Casa')

    
// create a map in the "map" div, set the view to a given place and zoom
var map = L.map('mapcircuit').setView([38.57156160678178, -7.908692129122894], 16);

// add an OpenStreetMap tile layer
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

// add a marker in the given location, attach some popup content to it and open the popup
var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/position.png',

    iconSize:[60, 40], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor:   [30, 40], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
});
L.marker([38.57266152778955, -7.907425130974091],{icon:greenIcon}).addTo(map)

    .bindPopup('Casa')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please share your code. But I think that you forgott to add the imports `leaflet.js` and `leaflet.css` in the second page

Comment: I shared above the code for my second page.

Comment: Where's your *javascript* defining the second map?

Comment: I call javascript file in the end of the page, file: maps.js 

The code of maps.js was added now to the original post. (Sorry i'm new at this) :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Name your map instances different:

```
// create a map in the "map" div, set the view to a given place and zoom
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([38.57156160678178, -7.908692129122894], 16);

// add an OpenStreetMap tile layer
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

// add a marker in the given location, attach some popup content to it and open the popup
var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/position.png',

    iconSize:[60, 40], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor:   [30, 40], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
});
L.marker([38.57266152778955, -7.907425130974091],{icon:greenIcon}).addTo(map)

    .bindPopup('Casa')

    
// create a map in the "map" div, set the view to a given place and zoom
var mapcircuit= L.map('mapcircuit').setView([38.57156160678178, -7.908692129122894], 16);

// add an OpenStreetMap tile layer
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(mapcircuit);

// add a marker in the given location, attach some popup content to it and open the popup
var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/position.png',

    iconSize:[60, 40], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor:   [30, 40], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
});
L.marker([38.57266152778955, -7.907425130974091],{icon:greenIcon}).addTo(mapcircuit)
    .bindPopup('Casa')
```

2. Be sure that your map has a CSS `height` and `width`, for example:

```
<div id="mapcircuit" style="height:100%; width:100%"></div>
```

3. Is the name of the javascript file `map_circuita.js` and not `map.js`?
   Because of  `<script src="app/js/map_circuita.js"></script>?`

Comment: Thank you a lot! it worked! and yes... i was with the wrong name on js file.